# ¿Como crear bien link canonical?

Tags: html, seo

Como puedo crear bien el link canonical ya que en la pagina de seigoo dice que no tengo link canonical en mi web este es el codigo

```
<link rel=”canonical” href=”https://miweb.es”/>
```

y el .httacces es:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

por lo que he visto me faltaria poner redireccion de index.php o html que vayan a mi midominio.es pero no se donde tengo que inplementarlo en el codigo, no se si falta algo por poner otros conceptos o errores de pagina....

el codigo que encontre para index.html/php es este:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(php|html)$[ http://www.ejemplo.com/](http://www.mydomain.com/)$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

es posible que la tengas bien implementada pero [Seigoo](https://seigoo.com) no la detecte porque no es relevante, es decir, si tu etiqueta canonical es https://miweb.com y la tienes puesta en la url https://miweb.com entonces no hará efecto y tal vez no la encuentre.

La otra posibilidad es que la tengas implementada en un sitio equivocado, recuerda siempre que debe ir entre las etiquetas  de tu web

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez sea las comillas incorrectas que tiene. Cambia esta: **`””`** por éste que es correcto: **`""`**

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://miweb.es"/>
```